# Rspec test failing due to the undefined method "in" for a Date class instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm attempting to test a method that uses the `at` method on a Date class instance.

ex: `start_at = day.at(ordering_range.open_time)`

and I get this error:

```
eval error: undefined method `at' for 2023-02-07 20:10:54.835826 -0500:Date
```

Event though `at` is instance method of Date outside of rspec

Is this an issue with rspec? Is it possible to test?

Answer (score 2):

[`at` is a class method](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Time.html#method-c-at), it's generally used to convert from number of seconds since the epoch to a Time object.

```
Time.at(1)  # 1969-12-31 16:00:01 -0800
```

Comment: Oh okay, I debugged the code and it's actually a date class instance. Now I'm really confused as to how this works. 

I've updated the test to be a date instance and it throws the same error

Comment: Date doesn't have an `at` method at all. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Rails provides a monkeypatch to `Time.at` but it really just makes it so that you can use Time or DateTime instances as the argument.  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-at_with_coercion